# Font management tool across multiple machines

Tags: fonts, font-management

I have mac pro, imac and mac air and all of which I use at various times in the work flow creating a range of media.

I have various fonts across all three and have been trying to manage with font book, which just isn't cutting it. It's time to move to something useful in my situation.

What should I look for in a package that will help manage fonts across my machines? Do I need a server solution or would something else work in this small office?

Answer (score 1):

Server.

Font Agent Pro From http://www.insidersoftware.com has a server version.

And so does Suitcase from http://www.extensis.com

Be aware, the font licenses should allow for the number of seats you are using.

I prefer FontAgentPro myself.

You might also look into Font Agent Pro's Workgroup Edition... designed to do what you need without a "server" feature: http://www.insidersoftware.com/FA_pro_wge.php

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'm reading about Font Agent and FontExplorer - I'm the only user on all three machines - so the license shouldn't be an issue. Just spendy for a server solution.

Comment: If you're the only users.. what I'd suggest is the non-server versions. Set up the folders and prefs on one machine, Then duplicate the folders to the other machines. I'm a one man operation and use FontAGent Pro. All I need do is duplicate the font directory on any machine and then export/import sets with FAP. I too find the server versions a bit pricey for small operations.

Comment: How about the cloud server options FAP folks are offering?