# Is there any open-source alternative to Fontlab out there?

Tags: software-recommendation, font-design, fontlab-studio

I used to work with Fontlab Studio to design and compile my fonts. Years have passed and my former Fontlab install vanished into the voids of a crashing harddisk.

Now that I'm gaining interest in font-design again, I used and abused the usual search engines, but I have not managed to find any free or open-source software out there with alike functionality which Fontlab offers.

Therefore I would love to know: "Is there any open-source alternative to Fontlab out there?"

(Preferably, it should be able to run on a Microsoft Windows operating system.)

Comment: If you have purchased a legit copy of Fontlab Studio, can you contact them for another download? I did that with Alien Skin software at least once.

Comment: @Voxwoman LOL, I wish… at the time I was working with Fontlab, I was employed in a local advertising agency. They owned the license, not me. Yet, that didn’t stop me from regaining interest in font design years later and – as I am not a full-fledged, investor-powered advertisement agency with the appropriate cashflow to license expensive software – I was looking for an open-source alternative that I can modify whenever I think it needs a tweak of bugfix (yep, I’m one of those designers with indeep c/c++ and Java coding abilities). Guess that explains my question from your point of view too? ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Open Source Font Editors:

1. [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io)
2. [gbdfed Bitmap Font Editor](http://sofia.nmsu.edu/~mleisher/Software/gbdfed/)
3. [BirdFont](http://birdfont.org/)

### Freeware Font Editors:

1. [Font Struct](http://fontstruct.com/)
2. [Bit font Maker](http://www.pentacom.jp/soft/ex/font/edit_canvas.html)
3. [Type light](http://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html)
4. [Font Constructor](http://www.fontconstructor.com/)
5. [Raster Font Editor](http://www.cylog.org/graphics/rasterfonteditor.jsp)

### Commercial Font Editors:

1. [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html)
2. ([Fontlab Studio](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/))

### Font Management:

1. [25 Font Management Tools Reviewed](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/05/25-font-management-tools-reviewed/)

### Search results for font management:

1. [What is a good free font management tool for linux?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/what-is-a-good-free-font-management-tool-for-linux)
2. [Font management tools for Mac](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10648/font-management-tools-for-mac)
3. [Font management tool across multiple machines](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12838/font-management-tool-across-multiple-machines)

### Misc.:

1. The upcoming [.91 release of Inkscape](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.91) claims to have 'type design feeatures'

Comment: Fontlab Studio is a font editor, so only *fontforge* satisfies my needs. But that doesn't mean I don't appreciate your efforts. As a matter a fact, fontforge might just be what I was looking for. Thanks! **EDIT** seems "Font Creator" should be listed as "Font Editor" too. ;)

Comment: Added Birdfont. Haven't used it, but looks interesting.

Comment: Fontforge is the big hitter. It comes with a steep learning curve, but that just goes with the territory -- no one ever accused FontLab of being intuitive ;)

Answer (score 10):

## [Fontforge](https://fontforge.github.io)

It can be a bit clunky on Windows and crash occasionally, but then it can do that sometimes on Linux, too.  Keep backups.  I edit all fonts directly in my Dropbox directory so I have access to a file history.

Its user interface is strange and the author has no intention to fix that any time soon.

Some parts of it, like the auto-hinting, are actually very good and I would argue are better than Fontlab.  Other parts of it are inferior.  I don't, for example, think the simplify algorithm is very good, particularly for quadratic splines (which is what you use for Truetype outlines).

Comment: The feature I am to date missing most in Fontforge is a way to easily preview while editing the glyphs of the font.