# What font is typically used for receipts?

Tags: font-identification

Can someone please help me identify the fonts used in these two receipts. I'm looking for downloadable free fonts that I can use to reproduce the same looking results.

The two receipts used different fonts.

[image]
[image]

Comment: offtopic, you sir are the first person I have ever seen buy anchovies ;)

Comment: @Matt_2.0 lol, those aren't my receipts. I would never pay $17.99 for pistachios.

Comment: @Matt I bought anchovies once...once.

Comment: 1.4 kilos of Pistachio, that's fairly good price - still you wanna cover all your food groups, looks like a nibble party!

Comment: Check out http://receiptfont.com/ (not free, but they have a lot of similar fonts)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like DA01 says, finding an exact match isn't happening.

The font in the receipt is a monospaced sans serif, so if you pick one that's close you could rough it up a bit to make it feel right: [Monaco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco_%28typeface%29), [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts), [OCR-A](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/ocr-a), and [OCR-B](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/ocr-b/). You'd probably have to rough it up a bit to make it feel more authentic.

If you want to get near the dot-matrix look, you can try FontFont's [Dot Matrix](https://www.fontfont.com/fonts/dot-matrix).

Or you could give this freebie a go: [Merchant Copy](http://www.fontspace.com/cumberland-fontworks/merchant-copy). Note the non-commercial license. It's a bit ugly but it's probably the closest I saw to what you want to do!

Comment: Just to clarify I don't want dirty fonts. I need the above font but clean without paper marks.

Answer (score 12):

These are likely embedded fonts on the dot-matrix or thermal receipt printer. As such, they likely aren't using the same type of fonts that you'd be using in your Adobe software, for instance.

That said, lots of people have made fonts to look like these types of printouts. Do a search on Myfonts.com for terms such as 'receipt', 'dot-matrix' and 'printer'.

Here's one that seems close: [Hypermarket](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/green-type/hypermarket/)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Receipt fonts are part of the cash register software. There is no source for the actual fonts that I am aware of. But you have a couple of options.

---

## 1. Use a substitute.

Ray Larabie's [Telidon Ink](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/telidon-ink/) is probably the closest match. There are lots of variations available.

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

And [Telidon](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/telidon/), the unsmudged version.

> [image]

[Fake Receipt](http://www.dafont.com/fake-receipt.font) in caps only.

> [image]

[Receipt Font](http://www.scootergraphics.com/receipt/), also caps.

> [image]

[Ticket De Caisse.](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/ticket-de-caisse/regular/) Caps reign supreme in this category.

> [image]

[Lineto has some good ones.](http://lineto.com/) Akkurat Mono would work well if output correctly. The site is hard to browse and completely devoid of deep links. You'll have to dig.

> [image]

---

## 2. Roll your own.

Receipt fonts are monospace and very modular. Have you considered creating your own font?

For this kind of project (a font with no kerning) font development isn't too tough, once you have the outlines. If you aren't familiar with the process, here are a few good references on GD.SE:

[Is there any open-source alternative to Fontlab out there?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19734/4216)
[How do you make a font in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/how-do-you-make-a-font-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 5):

Agreed that finding an exact font might be impossible.

In my opinion, closest matches if you're willing to settle for a pixel font that has similar appearance on similar font sizes are: [Telindon Heavy](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/telidon/) at 20px and [DPI-Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/dpi/) at 16-20px. Keep in mind that these fonts, while pixelated and blocked on the screen, might yield solid results depending on size, resolution and quality of printer.

These fonts appear better matches in relation to the letter design, if you get down to the conceptual detail (i.e.: lowercase "y" baseline above the regular x baseline, asterisk '*' has a horizontal and no vertical stroke, number '3' is not rounded on top half, etc).

If I were you, however, I'd be searching for a font with the most similar qualities possible, but with the flexibility of a regular font. By flexibility, I mean non-pixel font (thus not requiring specific font sizes in order not to break up), not blocked (in larger sizes the spaces between blocks will be too evident), with multiple weights, and support for a wide array of non english characters. If this is what you're looking for, and not the EXACT font you asked, then my recommendation is [Carbon](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/carbon/), hands down.

Good Luck.

EDIT: you should also look into two variants of carbon: [CarbonPlus](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/cadson-demak/carbon-plus/) and [Carbon C6](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/behaviour/carbon-c6/)

Comment: +1 for Carbon. Another very similar font, also from T-26, is [Automate](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/automate/).

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Answer (score 3):

A font called [Rysse - regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/aah-yes/rysse/regular/) comes close...

[image: sample 1]
[image: sample 2]
[image: sample 3]

Answer (score 2):

[**Dotty**](https://www.fontspace.com/kevin-richey/dotty) font by Kevin Richey would also be useful. It's free for commercial use.

[image: Dotty font]