# Font used for a receipt

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I struggled to find this font used to print a receipt. I have already tried several online tools without success.
It has some serifs and I'm almost sure it's a monospace but cannot figure out the name.
[image: sample]

Sorry for poor quality. If needed I could provide more samples.
Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the 4th question I've seen the last couple of months about which font is used for a receipt. Makes me curious, what do you need this for?

Comment: I would like to be able to produce programmatically thousands of receipts for training an algorithm.

Comment: OK, interesting. Makes me wonder even more :) When the training of the AI is done, how will you input receipts? I mean, if the input will be scanned physical receipts, shouldn't the training material also be in the same form and not clean digitally generated receipts? And isn't this just OCR, which already exists? Why is reading receipts different from reading anything else?

Comment: Do you know where this receipt is from? Do a bit of leg work and find the make and model of the system it was produced from and take it from there.

Comment: @AasimAzam unfortunetely this receipt was taken approx 200Km from where I am. Maybe an identical model of POS is installed somewhere near me but, who knows? Which is why I'm trying to render it programmatically.

Comment: @Wolff the problem is not the OCR itself but the meaning of the recognized text: let's say I want to identify the total of the receipt. Using a regex to catch the numbers separated from a dot or a comma could lead to mistakes since the receipt could have more rows. Furthermore identifying the rows could be hard due to the perspective in which the picture was taken. So my idea is to traing an AI model to recognize a specific portion of the image and sumit only that to the OCR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What font is typically used for receipts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20027/what-font-is-typically-used-for-receipts)

Answer (score 2):

A question like this comes up every other month! These fonts are always custom to the device manufacturer. They're never retail fonts. It looks like some kind of weird monospacing based on Bookman and some other nineteenth-century fonts. Maybe check out the Latin-alphabet characters of some font really intended for typesetting Far Eastern languages where all the characters are the same width. Macs come with PCMyungjo Regular, which is similar. ITC Souvenir Mono is also similar. (In general, these fonts always look really badly spaced. Normally, monospaced fonts heavily redesign the alphabet to make the characters look equal-width, so for instance totally remaking the 'I' and 'i'. Just monospacing a font without reproportioning the characters makes it look like there's a space either side of the 'i', for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

The most similar font I could find is pixFueler-D.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what the exact font is, but you can use [Merchant Copy](https://www.dafont.com/merchant-copy.font) to simulate receipts, it's actually pretty decent.

[image: Alphabet]

Answer (score 0):

As @copilot rightly points out, even modern receipt printers tend to use a small set of bitmap fonts stored in firmware and you are only transmitting control characters and the type as data to the device.

You will have better luck training on a variety of typefaces, but probably "near letter quality font" and "daisy wheel typeface" are good googling choices to find a mix.

You might try "Prestige 1012," "Elite," and of course "courier" and "letter gothic." Check the manuals of old Brother, NEC, IBM dot matrix printers and typewriters for potential type specimens to broaden your search.

If you are simulating the visual representation of printed receipts, you might start with a small pixel size rasterized type and then scale it up slightly to emphasize the typically lower DPI output.

The particular typeface you show is probably a naively-ripped version of some **Bodoni** variety and the lack of kerning reinforces the idea of it being a cheap firmware implementation. There are some differences in some glyphs (from the Bodoni fonts that I have on hand) that are clearly differences, but most of the deviation can be attributed to low-resolution aliasing in the output. If it is a thermal printer, it may also have dot gain/loss that looks like blur or posterization.