# What font is on this receipt?

Tags: font-identification

What is the font used on this receipt?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fonts on receipt printers are never a brand-name font, it's always a font designed for the printer's technical limitations of memory capacity and printing mechanism, probably by the manufacturers. [Receiptfont.com](https://www.receiptfont.com) sells many receipt fonts digitized.

See [a previous question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/129912/font-used-for-a-receipt/131137#131137) on this, and [another](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/147482/receipt-font-match).

Answer (score 1):

As [Copilot](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/66454/copilot) said, [receiptfont.com](https://www.receiptfont.com) is a really good starting point.

But if you want to save some money on receipt-font licenses, you can most of the time use a simple monospace font to imitate it.

[Azeret Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Azeret+Mono?category=Monospace) is good but don't go too hard and use Space Mono or any other extrem variation.

Regards, OrangeBlueHoney