# Receipt Font Match

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can Anyone help me determine what font is being used in this receipt?[image]

Comment: I often wonder *why* anyone needs to match a font on a receipt.... There may be legitimate reasoning. However, all I can think of is to alter reality `:)`

Answer (score 2):

We get these questions [quite often](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20027/what-font-is-typically-used-for-receipts). It's never a font available for sale, it's always something designed by the printer manufacturer, perhaps encoded pixel by pixel.

A few things in the same space are Helvetica Compressed and Monospaced, maybe some other monospaced fonts or try looking at the Latin character range of fonts designed for Far East languages, those often have similarly "naive" alphabets with odd proportions. More loosely, [Production Type](https://www.productiontype.com/fonts/), a French typeface studio, have made a thing of designing a lot of fonts inspired by the blocky nature of simplistic computer encodings or creating letterforms where the proportions are off. You might want to check out their [Minotaur Sans](https://www.productiontype.com/collection/minotaur_collection), [Proto Grotesk Mono](https://www.productiontype.com/collection/proto_collection) and [Dr](https://www.productiontype.com/family/dr) if you want to find something that suggests this style in a less literal way. PangramPangram's [Neue Machina](https://pangrampangram.com/products/neue-machina) is also a quite interesting take on this space.