# Tools for classifying and organizing fonts

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation, font-management

I have a fairly large collection of fonts, is there any automated method (via a tool or something) to organize them in groups according to their font family? If not, is there any sort of a list of 'font name – font family' pairs?

** note : the most important feature I look for is the software ability to automatically recognize and organize the fonts collection into families **

Comment: What do you mean by families? Most font managers will group fonts by family.. Actually most software will

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of font management software solutions out there.  I personally prefer [Suitcase Fusion](http://www.extensis.com/font-management/suitcase-fusion/) for individual but if you have a company I would suggest [Universal Type Server](http://www.extensis.com/font-management/universal-type-server/).  Both software are developed by Extensis.

If you use Adobe you could use their [Typekit](https://typekit.com/foundries/adobe).

Also related:

- [Font management tools for Mac](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10648/font-management-tools-for-mac)
- [What is a good free font management tool for linux?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/what-is-a-good-free-font-management-tool-for-linux)
- [Font management tool across multiple machines](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12838/font-management-tool-across-multiple-machines)
- [Recommend a good font management software for Windows 7](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/recommend-a-good-font-management-software-for-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

Two font managers I have used for the last few years [**Suitcase Fusion**](http://www.extensis.com/font-management/suitcase-fusion/) and [**FontExplorer X**](https://www.fontexplorerx.com/). Both are extremely useful solutions. I personally much prefer FontExplorer, which is what I currently use.

FontExplorer lets you easily and automatically organize fonts with Smart Sets. Manually sort your fonts in to groups. It has easy activation control with application-specific sets and a font request window that lets you quickly enable document specific fonts.

FonExplorer also lets you clean your OS and application font caches, inspect glyphs and OpenType features of your fonts and you can sync with a number of font stores like myfonts.com.

The new version also has a nice tiled font view, which (whilst not groundbreaking) is nice!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem before and i didn't find a successful solution so i did this:

I organized my fonts in a nested folder way

[image: Nested folders]

Now i use Linotype FontXplorer X (For mac, in windows i cannot replicate the function) and i search the fonts by path. So when i look for 'sans geometric' I get the fonts that are in that folder.

That's the best solution i found.

Comment: Tinkering you for the answer, I hope I can do this automatically .

Comment: I'm confused, you say you use FontExplorer but you use the OS folder structure? You can do what you are doing (but better) in FontExplorer in a number of ways